# Regex for case sensitive and conditions for the matching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match words with the following structure:

call NAME, 
or
call name;
that is, preceded by "call" and a blank space

And

NAME (whatever; 
that is, NAME+ blank space+(
and the same for the lower case

I learnt (?.) for case insensitiveness. How the complete regex command would be?

Comment: Please provide some example texts with expected outputs. Also, you meant `(?i)`, didn't you? Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: "NAME" shouldn't match but "call NAME" and "call name". Besides, "NAME (blablabla" and "name (blablabla" should match as well

Comment: but CALL name shouldn't match right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the actual requirements. What is known and what is not? The [`(?i)(?<=\bcall\s)name|name(?=\s+\()`](https://regex101.com/r/mF9dH1/1) does not make much sense to me.

Comment: The regex to match `name` in any case could be `(?i)name`. But is that what you want, or do you want to grab the name when `call` of any case is matched? Then it could be done with `(?i)call (.*)`. Depends on how your data input looks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:call (?i)name)|(?:(?i)name \\(.*)");

System.out.println(pattern.matcher("call NAME").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("call name").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("CALL name").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("NAME (blablabla").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("name (blablabla").matches());
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
true
true
```

Comment: whoever down voted, be a big boy, tell me why you down voted?